AWS DMS RDS -> S3 endpoint how to wrap strings in quotes
I am using AWS DMS to consume CDC logs from RDS Oracle. This works great, but for string columns which contain commas it is difficult for a reader to parse. Say we have in oracle RDS:
| col 1         | col2                |
| ------------- | ------------------- |
| a, b and c    | d,e and f           |
For any reader application it is impossible to reconstruct that if we have a csv output file with one row being:

a, b and c,d,e and f\n

since it is impossible to distinguish "data commas" from delimiter commas. I could not find any setting that would allow to "wrap" strings in (tripple)quotes. I could use some weirdo delimiter, but I think the standard way to solve this problem is using (tripple) quotes arround strings?
Source:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/dms_s3_endpoint

Wrapping strings and then setting csv_delimiter, csv_row_delimiter and csv_null_value S3 attributes will allow DMS to read the data, however, external readers will also have to be aware of these settings.
